# How scons tell different OS adn build different SConscript accordingly?

Tags: python, operating-system, scons

I've got several directories of source code, some for linux, some for mac, etc. How can I specify inside my SConstruct, that under linux, please execute:

```
SConscript(dirs=['linux'],     variant_dir='linux/build',     duplicate=0);
```

And under other operating system, execute other SConscript command?

Is there a convenient way to specify this?

Comment: You probably want to check the `PLATFORM` variable in the SCons environment and use that to conditionalize your build.  However, this is awfully lacking.  It's hard to tell the difference between Linux and FreeBSD using it.  So most folks rely on Python's `sys.platform` or `os.uname()` to get more information about the system you're running under to customize the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jszakmeiter's comment it good.

Another way might be to match the directory name of the code with the value for sys.platform and then use:

```
SConscript(dirs=[sys.platform],     variant_dir='%s/build'%sys.platform,     duplicate=0);
```

As a side note, I usually advise having the variant dirs as siblings to and not children of the source directories.

```
SConscript(dirs=[sys.platform],     variant_dir='build/%s'%sys.platform,     duplicate=0);
```